# Can an adverb act as an adjective?

Tags: грамматика

A waiter asks, "Что вы будете пить?"
The customer responds, "Просто воду, пожалуйста".

If просто is an adverb, why is вода altered?

Answer (score 4):

The customer's response is an ellipsis:

> — Что вы будете пить?
>
> — (Я буду пить) просто воду

, that means

> "What would you like to drink?"
>
> "(I would like to drink) just water." (or, literally, "simply water")

Regardless of whether the response uses an adverb or an adjective (*простую воду* "simple water"), the object (*воду*) still has to be put into the accusative that is governed by the verb *пить*, even though it's only inferred.